# comparing values of string in java

Tags: java, string, string-comparison

String username;

String password;

if (username!="admin" && password!="software")

```
        System.out.print("success");
```

else if (username!="admin" && password=="software")

```
        System.out.print("failure");
```

guyz could you plzz explain when admin and password are both equal to their respective values i.e. admin and software than it prints success but if i say username is equal to admin and password is not equal to software it also prints success again

Moreover, i took input in username and password like this

password =  Pass_input.getText();

username = Username_input.getText();

while Username_input and Pass_input are the JtextFields in java

Comment: Use .equals method to compare the strings, Your need is to compare string values whereas you are comparing objects in you scenario.

Comment: if (username.equals(user))
                {
                    if (password.equals(pass))
                    {
                         System.out.print("success");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print("failure wrong password");
                    }
                }

Comment: portion of code above is working absolutely fine but
        
        bro equal here commpare values what if i want to say that if username is not equal to admin and password is also not
        
        equal to software print failure wrong username and password what to do for that

Comment: else if (username=="admin" && password=="software") 

           //i am facing problem here it is printing nothing on the screen
            
                            {
                             System.out.print("failure wrong username and password");
                            }

Comment: else if (username.equals(user)== false && password.equals(pass)==false)
        {
            System.out.print("failure wrong username and password");
        }

Comment: it worked like this if it is correct or not ? what is your opinion @Rishaldevsingh

Comment: then use something like (!username.equals(user)), here "!" will give you the opposite of equals.